# How do I prerender variable in angular directive for ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to create reusable directive something like grid. I want to define data and actions (edit, delete,...) in controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {id: 1, name: 'aaa'},
        {id: 2, name: 'bbb'},
        {id: 3, name: 'ccc'},
    ];

    $scope.actions = [
        {label:'edit', href:'#edit/{{row.id}}'},
        {label:'delete', ngClick:'doAction({name:\'delete\', id:row.id})'}
    ];

    $scope.doAction = function (name, id) {
        $scope[name](id);
    }

    $scope.delete = function (row) {
        console.log('deleted' + row.id);
    }
});
```

Problem is how to prerender part of the directive for `ng-repeat`.

```
app.directive('list', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            actions: '=',
            doAction: '&'
        },
        template:
            '<li ng-repeat="row in data">{{row.name}} ' +
                '<span ng-repeat="action in actions">' +
                    '<a href="{{action.href}}" ng-click="{{action.ngClick}}">' +
                        '{{action.label}}' + 
                    '</a> ' +
                '</span>' +
             '</li> '
    }
});
```

Now is in action link `<a href="#edit/{{row.id}}">` but I need this `<a href="#edit/1>`.
And for delete ng-click doesn't work. I try to play with compile, but I was not able to do it. Can you help me? May be actions could be sub-directive of list, the problem is same.

Here is live template in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/O7hXXgQb0Num1xZs5Xrt?p=preview

note: I know I can modify actions definition in ctrl `href:'#edit'` and then `<a href="{{action.href}}/{{row.id}}">` but this is not very good solution because in other usages of this directive could be other params from `$scope.data` which I can pass to action, not always `{{row.id}}`

**Updated example**: Added ng-click for delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Langdon, sorry i didnt read the question to full. I have another answer like listed below,

@urban_racoons pls. let me know if this solution works. I changed the template part and added a controller to the directive

```
app.directive('list', function () {
    return {
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                actions: '='
            },
      controller:function($scope,$interpolate){
        $scope.hrefer = function(action,row ){
          return $interpolate(action.href)({row:row})
        }        
      },
        template: 
        '<li ng-repeat="row in data">{{row.name}} ' +
          '<span ng-repeat="action in actions">' +
            '<a href="{{hrefer(action,row)}}">{{action.label}}</a> ' +
          '</span>' + 
        '</li> '
        }
});
```

Comment: Check his note at the bottom of his question. ;)

Comment: @rajkamal thanks, this work but only for href but I have also `ng-click` and for this actions this approach doesn't work. I updated example for delete action to see what I mean. E.g. I need in template `ng-click="doAction({name:'delete', id: row.id})"` and if I create similar interpolate for `ng-click` this doesn't work. This action is inserted into ng-click but may be angular doesn't know about it. Do you know how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a little clunky, but it works and I think it's generic enough to meet your needs:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'aaa'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bbb'},
    {id: 3, name: 'ccc'},
  ];

  $scope.actions = [
    {label:'edit', href: function(row) { return '#edit/' + row.id;}},
    {label:'delete', href: function(row) { return '#delete/' + row.id;}}
  ];

});

app.directive('list', function () {
    return {
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                actions: '='
            },
            template: 
        '<li ng-repeat="row in data">{{row.name}} ' +
          '<span ng-repeat="action in actions">' +
            '<a href="{{action.href(row)}}">{{action.label}}</a> ' +
          '</span>' + 
        '</li> '

        }
});
```

Comment: thanks, this approach works fine for `href` but I have also `ng-click` for some actions and for it doesn't work. I updated example for delete action to see what I mean. E.g. I need in template `ng-click="doAction({name:'delete', id: row.id})"` and if I create similar action definition like `ngClick: function (row) { return 'doAction({name:\'delete\', id:'+row.id+'})'}` this doesn't work. Can you help me again?